# Speed up DensityHistogram rendering (display)

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning

When I tried to present some pre-calculated density histograms inside Manipulate I noticed that the display of `DensityHistogram` is extremely slow. Here is a simple benchmark:

```
Second[x_] := x[[2]];
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[Abs@Random[]], {5, 10^4}];
histograms = 
  DensityHistogram[#, 30, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] & /@ 
   data;
contourplots = 
  ListContourPlot[Second@HistogramList[#, 30], 
     InterpolationOrder -> 0] & /@ data;
rasterizedSmall = Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> Small] & /@ histograms;
rasterizedMedium = Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ histograms;

t = AbsoluteTime[];
histograms
AbsoluteTime[] - t
(* ==> 1.6410939 *)    

t = AbsoluteTime[];
contourplots
AbsoluteTime[] - t
(* ==> 0.0860049 *)

t = AbsoluteTime[];
rasterizedSmall
AbsoluteTime[] - t
(* ==> 0.0390022 *)    

t = AbsoluteTime[];
rasterizedMedium
AbsoluteTime[] - t
(* ==> 0.0280016 *)
```

So we see that it takes almost two seconds to display five pre-calculated density histograms, while five list contour plots are displayed in ~100 ms.

**What is wrong and is there an easy way to fix it?**

(I'm using mma 8.0.1 on Win 7 and I've already turned off antialising)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to inspect your graphics carefully. What you do here is you compare apples and oranges. While your `DensityHistogram` contains about 100 colors (89 in this special case)

[image]

the `ListContourPlot` contains only 10 colors.

[image]

This is what you could have observed directly. Under the hood happens more which leads to the slowness of the `DensityHistogram`. The `ListContourPlot` uses the relatively new `GraphicsComplex` directive which works like that:

When you want to draw a polygon or rectangle or whatever, you don't use the coordinates directly because adjacent polygons share points and you would repeat the same coordinates over and over again. Instead, you start with a list of all coordinates and then you *refer* only to the index of those coordinates.

Additionally, while `DensityHistogram` creates many many `Rectangle` directives, `ListContourPlot` creates only some `Polygon`-directives and includes many polygons in one call:

> `Polygon[{pt11, pt12,...},{pt21,...},...}]`
>   represents a collection of polygons.

This leads usually to speed improvement.

Therefore, your `ListContourPlot` is faster because it

1. is less complex in general
2. uses `GraphicsComplex`
3. uses a few `Polygon` calls instead of many `Rectangle` calls

To test this, just look at the `InputForm` of your `DensityHistogram`. You could write some lines of code to extract all coordinates, build a `GraphicsComplex` and convert the many `Rectangle`s into `Polygon` calls:

```
histPatrick =
 With[{hist = DensityHistogram[
     RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[Abs@Random[]], 10^4], 30, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]},
  Block[{coords, coordRule, tmpgr},
   tmpgr = 
    hist /. Rectangle[a : {x1_, y1_}, b : {x2_, y2_}] :> 
      Polygon[{a, {x2, y1}, b, {x1, y2}}];
   coords = Cases[tmpgr, Polygon[{a__}] :> a, Infinity];
   coordRule = Thread[coords -> Range[Length[coords]]];
   tmpgr /. 
     Graphics[dirs_, rest___] :> 
      Graphics[
       GraphicsComplex[coords, 
        dirs /. Polygon[pts_] :> Polygon[pts /. coordRule]], 
       rest] /. {start___, Longest[polys__Polygon], end___} :> {start,
       Distribute[{polys}, Polygon], end}
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: +1 Wow, works great! This should be done by default by mma.